# Extracting upload and download bandwidth from iperf2 output

Tags: tcp, stm32, ethernet, bandwidth, iperf

I use iperf2. iperf2 has been set in the server mode on STM32 board. Client mode is used on Windows PC.
I'd like to receive transfer bandwidth statistics in upload and download terms.

```
iperf -c 192.168.21.25 -d -t 5 -f m:

[220] local 192.168.21.1 port 60602 connected with 192.168.21.25 port 5001

[252] local 192.168.21.1 port 5001 connected with 192.168.21.25 port 49155

[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth

[252]  0.0- 5.0 sec  48.5 MBytes  81.3 Mbits/sec

[220]  0.0- 5.0 sec  23.1 MBytes  38.7 Mbits/sec
```

=========

```
iperf -c 192.168.21.25 -r -t 5 -f m

[216] local 192.168.21.1 port 60531 connected with 192.168.21.25 port 5001

[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth

[216]  0.0- 5.0 sec  33.9 MBytes  56.8 Mbits/sec

[212] local 192.168.21.1 port 5001 connected with 192.168.21.25 port 49154

[212]  0.0- 5.0 sec  54.9 MBytes  92.1 Mbits/sec
```

What are the rules to detect upload and download bandwidth in these responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[] local port <port>` gives the client's port while the connection with gives the server port.

So in example 1,  `[220]` is the traffic from the client to server, and [252] is from the server to the client.